# Binding of Checkbox IsChecked to EntityFramework not working in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf, mvvm, checkbox

Summary: How can the Isdone property in the data Model be updated from the UI?
         (Nothing I've read on Google has helped. I'm hoping there is a simple answer.)

I'm trying to be as complete as possible and only showing pertinent code.

Upon initialization, the ListView's checkbox is correctly shown as being checked by the database Actiontaken's value.

However, when the Checkbox is checked from the UI, the set code of the Isdone property is not hit.

In Visual Studio 2010, I have separated my solution into the following projects:
1. Chaos.Data,
2. Chaos.DataService,
3. TestClient.

Chaos.Data provides data from a database using the EntityFramework with partial classes. In this I have added a separate file for separate business rules with:

```
namespace Chaos.Data
{
 partial class Lab
   {
    private Boolean? isdone;
    public virtual Boolean? Isdone
    {
        get
        {
            isdone = (Actiontaken == 1 || Actiontaken == 129) ? true : false;
            return isdone;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.isdone != value)
            {
                this.isdone = value;
                this.Actiontaken = 1;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Isdone");
                if (this.isdone == true) this.setallcheckbox("Isdone");
            }
        }
    }
```

The Chaos.DataService is a WCF Service. In this, I have defined:

```
namespace Chaos.DataService
{
  [OperationContract]
    public IEnumerable<Lab> GetAllLabs(String groupid, DateTime? encountertime)
    {
        if (encountertime == null) return null;

        using (var context = new ChaosModel())
        {
            var query = from lab in context.Labs
                        where lab.Groupid == groupid && lab.Tposted.Date <= ((DateTime)encountertime).Date
                        select lab;

            var result = context.CreateDetachedCopy(query.ToList());
            return result;
        }
    }
```

}

TestClient uses a reference to the Chaos.DataService (...and yes, just to be safe, I've updated the service reference in the TestClient.) The TestClient has its view as:

XAML

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Labs}"  
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="12,99,0,103" Name="listViewLabs" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Done" Width="40">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Isdone, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
    .................
```

C# Code-behind:

```
 namespace Chaos.UI.View
 {
    public partial class PatientLabsWindow : Window
    {
        public PatientLabsWindow(EncounterDetail encounter)
        { 
          InitializeComponent();

        ViewModelPatientLabs vm = new ViewModelPatientLabs(encounter);
        this.DataContext = vm;
        vm.CloseAction = new Action(() => this.Close());
    }
  }
}
```

In the ViewModel, I've defined:

```
 namespace Chaos.UI.ViewModel
 {
  class ViewModelPatientLabs : ViewModelBase
 {
        private ChaosServiceClient serviceClient = new ChaosServiceClient();

        // Constructor
        public ViewModelPatientLabs(EncounterDetail encounter)
        {
            this.Encounter = encounter;
        }

    private EncounterDetail encounter;
    public EncounterDetail Encounter 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.encounter;
        }
        set
        {
                this.encounter = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Encounter");
                this.GetAllLabs();
        }
    }

    private void GetAllLabs()
    {
        // consume the WCF service.
        this.serviceClient.GetAllLabsCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Labs = e.Result;
        };

        // call the WCF service -- Async
        this.serviceClient.GetAllLabsAsync(Encounter.groupid, Encounter.tencounter);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Lab> labs;
    public IEnumerable<Lab> Labs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.labs;
        }
        set
        {
            this.labs = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Labs");
        }
    }

}
}
```

If I've missed something, please let me know.

Again, to reiterate, the ListView's checkbox is correctly updated from the database model. But checking in the box from the UI does NOT hit the set code for Isdone in the added Labs business class.

How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Edit:  Lab is a defined class in the Chaos.Data namespace. It was generated by Telerik DataAccess as

```
  namespace Chaos.Data  
   {
  public partial class Lab : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
        ......
       }
     }
```

So as not to touch this automatically generated file, I added my own additions with a separate file to the partial class as show above.

Edit:  I am very new to all this. I find it interesting to note that when the service is updated in the client project, WCF ADDED my partial class to the Lab entity as:

```
  namespace Chaos.UI.ChaosService {
   using System.Runtime.Serialization;
   using System;
 ..............................

[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Nullable<bool> IsdoneField;
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class Lab : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject,      
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {....

...............

 [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Nullable<bool> IsdoneField;
```

and the Labs being returned from the WCF query is of type IEnumerable<> not an observable collection. So is the problem that the View binding is updating the field in WCF and never being transmitted back to the model???

Plz help somebody??

Comment: where is ObservableCollection<Labs> collection located?

Comment: Labs is defined in the Chaos.Data project in EntitiesModel.cs. This file was built automatically by Telerik DataAccess Update Model from Database and is defines as: public IQueryable<Lab> Labs 
  {
   get
   {
    return this.GetAll<Lab>();
   }
  }

Comment: And you want Isdone's setter property get triggered whenever it is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to ALL of this, but I found this to work in my case.

In my particular case, I need to perform a kind of grouping of multiple checkboxes on the same row of the UI. So, ultimately, I needed to know which checkbox was being clicked and on what row. In summary, this was going to need a parameter call for the UI binding. Sticking completely with the MVVM model would require adding something like the RelayCommand or other helper classes. Since I am already using a WCF service to communicate with the Data layer (Model), I decided to generalize the "View" and allow some code-behind. (Anybody, please correct this if it is too very wrong).

As was stated in the initial problem, the set{} method on the Isdone property in the Data Model was never being hit. I suspect this is because the WCF service was not being used to forward the property to the backend. Further, the UI binding was to Isdone, but there is no reference to the Entity Isdone is on.

Long story short, these changes made it work:
In the UI, added to the ListView

```
SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLab}"
```

In the UI, added Click to the checkbox:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Isdone, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="chkIsDone" Click="chkIsDone_Click" />
```

In the code-behind, added:

```
  void chkIsDone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as CheckBox;
        Lab lab = (Lab)cb.DataContext;
        if (lab.Isdone == true) this.setallcheckbox(lab, "Isdone");
        listViewLabs.SelectedItem = lab;
    }
```

In the ViewModel, added:

```
  private Lab currentLab;
    public Lab CurrentLab
    {
        get
        {
            return this.currentLab;
        }

        set
        {
            this.currentLab = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentLab");
        }
    }
```

Now the View correctly displays and the Isdone property is correctly set on the specific row it was clicked on.

I am more then interested if anybody has a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make IsDone's setter property get triggered whenever it is clicked, you need to make Lab implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and raises the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event on the IsDone's setter property.

Here is a working example.

## View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUserControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Labs}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Done" Width="40">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsDone, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {    
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}    
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Labs = new[] { new Lab { IsDone = true } };
    }    
    public IEnumerable<Lab> Labs { get; set; }
}    
public class Lab : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool? _isDone;
    public bool? IsDone
    {
        get { return _isDone; }
        set
        {
            _isDone = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDone");
        }
    }    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @yulaim Lab is defined as public partial class Lab : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
Please see my edits above...It still doesn't work????

Comment: @yulaim Please note that Isdone is not part of the original entity, but rather added in a separate file using the partial class Lab. Does this matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, I just tried it and it still working with partial.

Comment: @AlanWayne, How about removing this code `if (this.isdone != value)`

Comment: Umm...In code-behind it works. I have this set up in an MVVM pattern using a WCF service between the client project and the Data Model.  I must be missing something in the wiring, but don't know where??? Thanks for help!

Comment: Umm...In code-behind it works. I have this set up in an MVVM pattern using a WCF service between the client project and the Data Model.  I must be missing something in the wiring, but don't know where??? Thanks for help!